# User validation loop 'hangs'

Tags: c++

Here is my source code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{   
   int numBoxes,         // Number of boxes of cookies sold by one child
   totalBoxes = 0,       // Accumulates total boxes sold by the entire troop
   numSeller = 1;        // Counts the number of children selling cookies

   double averageBoxes;  // Average number of boxes sold per child

 // WRITE CODE TO INITIALIZE THE totalBoxes ACCUMLATOR TO 0 AND
 // THE numSeller COUNTER TO 1.


 cout << "             **** Cookie Sales Information **** \n\n";

 // Get the first input
 cout << "Enter number of boxes of cookies sold by seller " << numSeller
      << " (or -1 to quit): ";
 cin  >> numBoxes;

// WRITE CODE TO START A while LOOP THAT LOOPS WHILE numBoxes
// IS NOT EQUAL TO -1, THE SENTINEL VALUE.

while (numBoxes != -1)
{
       // WRITE CODE TO ADD numBoxes TO THE totalBoxes ACCUMULATOR.
       // WRITE CODE TO ADD 1 TO THE numSeller COUNTER.


       totalBoxes += numBoxes;

       numSeller++;
       cout << "Please enter amount of boxes sold by the next seller: ";
       cin >> numBoxes;


}


// WHEN THE LOOP IS EXITED, THE VALUE STORED IN THE numSeller COUNTER
// WILL BE ONE MORE THAN THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SELLERS. SO WRITE CODE
// TO ADJUST IT TO THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SELLERS.
numSeller -= 1;


if (numSeller == 0)
  cout << "\nNo boxes were sold.\n";
else
{  
   // WRITE CODE TO ASSIGN averageBoxes THE COMPUTED AVERAGE NUMBER 
   // OF BOXES SOLD PER SELLER.
   averageBoxes = (double)totalBoxes / (double)numSeller;
   // WRITE CODE TO PRINT OUT THE NUMBER OF SELLERS AND AVERAGE NUMBER
   // OF BOXES SOLD PER SELLER.
   cout << "The average number of boxes sold by the " << numSeller << " sellers was " << averageBoxes << endl;
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

The program takes input from the user, adds together the amounts added until the sentinel value is met and then displays the number of sellers and the average boxes sold of said sellers. 
My issue is with adding another while loop for user validation. 
If I enter..
10
-10
24
-1
The output is "The average number of boxes sold by the 3 sellers was 8."
This is incorrect, as the output *should* be..
"The average number of boxes sold by the 2 sellers was 17.
I've tried various while loops to for user validation inside the original while loop but it hangs and never goes anywhere if I enter anything below -1. 
I'm guessing my logic is wrong but I really just cannot figure this one out.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to step over the newline character on a subsequent `cin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the problem this way: Each iteration of the `while` loop should ask the user for input exactly once. Each time you ask the user for input, you can either use that input or discard it. So you can take this code:

```
totalBoxes += numBoxes;

numSeller++;
cout << "Please enter amount of boxes sold by the next seller: ";
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
if (numBoxes >= 0)
{
    totalBoxes += numBoxes;
    numSeller++;
}
else
{
    cout << "That is not a valid number of boxes. Naughty.\n"
}
cout << "Please enter amount of boxes sold by the next seller: ";
```